# Joining two matrices, one with numbers and the other percentages

Tags: matrix, append, stata

I have two matrices, cases and percentages. I want to combine both with the columns alternating between the two i.e. cases [c1] percent [c1] cases [c2] percent [c2]...

```
tab year region if sex==1, matcell(cases)
tab year region, matcell(total)
mata:st_matrix("percent", 100 * st_matrix("cases"):/st_matrix("total"))


matrix list cases

      c1    c2    c3    c4    c5    c6    c7    c8    c9   c10
r1  1313  1289  1121  1176  1176  1150  1190  1184  1042   940  
r2   340   359   357   366   383   332   406   367   352   272
r3   260   246   266   265   270   259   309   306   266   283
r4   271   267   293   277   317   312   296   285   265   253
r5   218   249   246   213   264   255   247   221   229   220
r6   215   202   157   202   200   204   220   183   176   180
r7   178   193   218   199   194   195   201   187   172   159
r8   127   111   107   130   133    99   142   143   131   114
r9    64    68    85    74    70    60    59    70    76    61


. matrix list percent, format(%2.1f)

percent[9,10]
      c1    c2    c3    c4    c5    c6    c7    c8    c9   c10
r1  70.1  71.2  67.3  67.2  66.9  71.5  72.6  72.5  74.9  73.2
r2  65.3  65.2  69.1  64.4  68.0  70.5  72.0  64.8  66.4  64.9
r3  74.7  73.7  74.7  69.2  68.9  67.6  70.5  72.3  79.4  80.9
r4  66.3  72.6  72.9  74.9  72.7  73.8  72.2  73.3  74.9  71.7
r5  68.8  67.1  66.0  63.6  67.2  67.1  65.2  67.4  68.6  73.8
r6  73.1  72.9  69.2  63.7  67.6  68.0  72.4  68.8  74.9  78.9
r7  64.5  60.3  69.9  70.6  69.3  78.3  72.3  65.8  71.4  71.3
r8  66.1  64.2  63.3  74.7  69.3  56.9  70.6  70.1  63.9  57.9
r9  77.1  73.9  70.2  74.0  71.4  73.2  81.9  72.9  87.4  74.4
```

How do I combine both the matrices?

currently I have tried: `matrix final=cases, percent` but it just puts them beside each other? I want it so each column alternates between cases and percent.

I will then use `putexcel` command to put them into an already formatted table with columns of cases and percentages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116454/discussion-between-exodia16-and-nick-cox).

Comment: As in earlier threads, I note here an absence of reproducible examples. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for good practice on SO and http://www.statalist.org/forums/help for Stata-specific advice, much of what carries over with obvious omissions or modifications to Stata questions. Good questions make answers more likely; busy people may sometimes flag that a question needs improvement, but often they will just ignore a question as requiring too much work to set up an example and code.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by supporting Nick Cox's comments.

The problem is, there is no simple solution for combining matrices as you desire. Nevertheless, it is simple to achieve the results you want, by taking a very much different path from the one you outlined. It's no fun to write an essay describing the technique in natural language; it's much simpler to demonstrate it using code, as I do below, and as I expect Nick might have been inclined to do.

By not providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, as described in the link Nick provided to you, you've discouraged others from showing you where you've gone off the tracks.

```
// create a minimal amount of sample data hopefully similar to actual data
clear
input year region sex
2001 1 1 
2001 1 2
2001 1 2
2002 1 1
2002 1 2
2001 2 1
2002 2 1
2002 2 2
end
list, clean noobs
// use collapse to generate summaries equivalent to two tabs
generate male = sex==1
collapse (count) total=male (sum) cases=male, by(year region)
list, clean noobs
generate percent = 100*cases/total
keep year region total percent
// flatten and interleave the columns
reshape wide total percent, i(year) j(region)
drop year
list, clean noobs
// now use export excel to output,
//  or use mkmat to load into a matrix and use putexcel to output
```

Comment: After the fact, it strikes me that you could construct a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) - an identity-like matrix consisting of ones and zeros, with no more than a single one in each row and column, which when multiplied by your "side by side" matrix yields a similarly-sized matrix with the columns permuted into the order in which you want them. And, by gosh, there it is in `help [M-1] permutation`. Still, not the best way to go here.